# Azure devops Variables and Terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform0.12+

I am trying to create a azure key vault with the help of terraform where i want to save my DB password in my azure devops pipeline because obviously I cannot hardcode it to my tfvars file.
As u can see i m creating an empty job and saving my password variable with value in pipeline

[image]

but I am not able to understand why my terraform plan is waiting in console like it is asking user to enter the password

below is snapshot of LOG:

[image]

can u please help me that what I am missing here ??

Also , I have i m passing my password in command line : then I am getting below error :

[image]

> 2022-05-13T05:11:00.5948619Z [31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mbuilding account: getting authenticated object ID: Error listing Service Principals: autorest.DetailedError{Original:adal.tokenRefreshError{message:"adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '401'. Response body: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret provided. Ensure the secret being sent in the request is the client secret value, not the client secret ID, for a secret added to app 'a527faff-6956-4b8a-93ad-d9a14ab41610'.\r\nTrace ID: 81c1b1e8-1b0c-4f21-ad90-baf277d43801\r\nCorrelation ID: c77d437b-a6e8-4a74-8342-1508de00fa3a\r\nTimestamp: 2022-05-13 05:11:00Z","error_codes":[7000215],"timestamp":"2022-05-13 05:11:00Z","trace_id":"81c1b1e8-1b0c-4f21-ad90-baf277d43801","correlation_id":"c77d437b-a6e8-4a74-8342-1508de00fa3a","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000215"} Endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0", resp:(*http.Response)(0xc00143c000)}, PackageType:"azure.BearerAuthorizer", Method:"WithAuthorization", StatusCode:401, Message:"Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://graph.windows.net/***/servicePrincipals?%24filter=appId+eq+%27a527faff-6956-4b8a-93ad-d9a14ab41610%27&api-version=1.6", ServiceError:[]uint8(nil), Response:(*http.Response)(0xc00143c000)}[0m
> 2022-05-13T05:11:00.5952404Z [31m│[0m [0m

Comment: Did you declare `HIVE_ADMIN_PASSWORD` var in your *.RG config files? Usually vars are in small case.

Comment: .rg confg files ? where it is ?? it is taking the password now but showing the authentication error of object id etc don't know why

Comment: sorry, *.tf config files.. was typing with phone then..

Comment: what should i add in .tf file ?? as i can't give value to this password its a secret